# Why is my multiclass keras model not training at a high accuracy despite parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

Firstly I read in my cvs file which contained a 1 or 0 matrix

```
df = pd.read_csv(url)
print(df.head())    
print(df.columns)
```

Next I gathered the Pictures and resized them

```
image_directory = 'Directory/'
dir_list = os.listdir(path)
print("Files and directories in '", image_directory, "' :")  
# print the list
print(dir_list)
```

They were saved into an X2 variable.

```
SIZE = 200
X_dataset = []
for i in tqdm(range(df.shape[0])):
    img2 = cv2.imread("Cell{}.png".format(i), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_directory +df['ID'][i], target_size=(SIZE,SIZE,3))
    #numpy array of each image at size 200, 200, 3 (color)
    img = np.array(img)
    img = img/255.
    X_dataset.append(img)

X2 = np.array(X_dataset)
print(X2.shape)
```

I created the y2 data by getting the cvs data, dropping two columns and getting a shape of (1000, 16)

```
y2 = np.array(df.drop(['Outcome', 'ID'], axis=1))
print(y2.shape)
```

I then did the train_test_split
*I wonder if my random state or test_size is not optimal*

```
X_train2, X_test2, y_train2, y_test2 = train_test_split(X2, y2, random_state=10, test_size=0.3)
```

Next, I created a sequential model
SIZE = (200,200,3) which was made above in the resized model.

```
model2 = Sequential()

model2.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(10, 10), activation="relu", input_shape=(SIZE,SIZE,3)))
model2.add(BatchNormalization())
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5)))
model2.add(Dropout(0.2))

model2.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model2.add(BatchNormalization())
model2.add(Dropout(0.2))

model2.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation="relu"))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model2.add(BatchNormalization())
model2.add(Dropout(0.2))

model2.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model2.add(BatchNormalization())
model2.add(Dropout(0.2))

model2.add(Flatten())
model2.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.5))
model2.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.5))
model2.add(Dense(16, activation='sigmoid'))

#Do not use softmax for multilabel classification
#Softmax is useful for mutually exclusive classes, either cat or dog but not both.
#Also, softmax outputs all add to 1. So good for multi class problems where each
#class is given a probability and all add to 1. Highest one wins. 

#Sigmoid outputs probability. Can be used for non-mutually exclusive problems.
#like multi label, in this example.
#But, also good for binary mutually exclusive (cat or not cat). 

model2.summary()

#Binary cross entropy of each label. So no really a binary classification problem but
#Calculating binary cross entropy for each label. 
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(
    learning_rate=0.02,
    beta_1=0.8,
    beta_2=0.9999,
    epsilon=1e-9,
    name='Adamax')

model2.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', 'mse' ])
```

The model uses a custom optimizer, ands the shape generated has 473,632 trainable params.

I then specify the sample weight which was calculated by taking the highest sampled number and  divided the other numbers by that.

```
sample_weight = {     0:1,
                      1:0.5197368421,
                      2:0.4385964912,
                      3:0.2324561404,
                      4:0.2302631579,
                      5:0.399122807,
                      6:0.08114035088,
                      7:0.5723684211,
                      8:0.08552631579,
                      9:0.2061403509,
                      10:0.3815789474,
                      11:0.125,
                      12:0.08333333333,
                      13:0.1206140351,
                      14:0.1403508772,
                      15:0.4824561404
                      }
```

finally I ran the model.fit

```
history = model2.fit(X_train2, y_train2, epochs=25, validation_data=(X_test2, y_test2), batch_size=64, class_weight = sample_weight, shuffle = False)
```

My issue was that the model was maxing out at around 30 to 40% accuracy. I looked into it, and they said tuning the learning rate was important. I also saw that raising the epochs would help to a point, as would lowering the batch size.

Is there any other thing I may have missed? I noticed the worse models only predicted one class frequently (100% normal, 0% anything else) but the better model predicted on a sliding scale where some items were at 10% and some at 70%.

I also wonder if I inverted my sample weights, my item 0 has the most items in it... Should it be inverted, where 1 sample 1 counts for 2 sample 0s?

Things I tried.

- Changing the batch size down to 16 or 8. (resulted in longer epoch times, slightly better results)
- Changing the learning rate to a lower number (resulted in slightly better results, but over more epochs)
- Changing it to 100 epochs (results plateaued around 20 epochs usually.)
- Attempting to create more params higher filters, larger initial kernel size, larger initial pool size, more and higher value dense layers. (This resulted in it eating the RAM and not getting much better results.)
- Changing the optimizer to Adam or RAdam or AdamMax. (Didn't really change much, the other optimizers sucked though). I messed with the beta_1 and epsilon too.
- Revising the Cvs. (the data is fairly vague, had help and it still was hard to tell)
- Removing bad data (I didn't want to get rid of too many pictures.)

Edit: Added sample accuracy. This one was unusually low, but starts off well enough (accuracy initially is 25.9%)

```
14/14 [==============================] - 79s 6s/step - loss: 0.4528 - accuracy: 0.2592 - mse: 0.1594 - val_loss: 261.8521 - val_accuracy: 0.3881 - val_mse: 0.1416
Epoch 2/25
14/14 [==============================] - 85s 6s/step - loss: 0.2817 - accuracy: 0.3188 - mse: 0.1310 - val_loss: 22.7037 - val_accuracy: 0.3881 - val_mse: 0.1416
Epoch 3/25
14/14 [==============================] - 79s 6s/step - loss: 0.2611 - accuracy: 0.3555 - mse: 0.1243 - val_loss: 11.9977 - val_accuracy: 0.3881 - val_mse: 0.1416
Epoch 4/25
14/14 [==============================] - 80s 6s/step - loss: 0.2420 - accuracy: 0.3521 - mse: 0.1172 - val_loss: 6.6056 - val_accuracy: 0.3881 - val_mse: 0.1416
Epoch 5/25
14/14 [==============================] - 80s 6s/step - loss: 0.2317 - accuracy: 0.3899 - mse: 0.1151 - val_loss: 4.9567 - val_accuracy: 0.3881 - val_mse: 0.1415
Epoch 6/25
14/14 [==============================] - 80s 6s/step - loss: 0.2341 - accuracy: 0.3899 - mse: 0.1141 - val_loss: 2.7395 - val_accuracy: 0.3881 - val_mse: 0.1389
Epoch 7/25
14/14 [==============================] - 76s 5s/step - loss: 0.2277 - accuracy: 0.4128 - mse: 0.1107 - val_loss: 2.3758 - val_accuracy: 0.3881 - val_mse: 0.1375
Epoch 8/25
14/14 [==============================] - 85s 6s/step - loss: 0.2199 - accuracy: 0.4106 - mse: 0.1094 - val_loss: 1.4526 - val_accuracy: 0.3881 - val_mse: 0.1319
Epoch 9/25
14/14 [==============================] - 76s 5s/step - loss: 0.2196 - accuracy: 0.4151 - mse: 0.1086 - val_loss: 0.7962 - val_accuracy: 0.3881 - val_mse: 0.1212
Epoch 10/25
14/14 [==============================] - 80s 6s/step - loss: 0.2187 - accuracy: 0.4140 - mse: 0.1087 - val_loss: 0.6308 - val_accuracy: 0.3744 - val_mse: 0.1211
Epoch 11/25
14/14 [==============================] - 81s 6s/step - loss: 0.2175 - accuracy: 0.4071 - mse: 0.1086 - val_loss: 0.5986 - val_accuracy: 0.3242 - val_mse: 0.1170
Epoch 12/25
14/14 [==============================] - 80s 6s/step - loss: 0.2087 - accuracy: 0.3968 - mse: 0.1034 - val_loss: 0.4003 - val_accuracy: 0.3333 - val_mse: 0.1092
Epoch 13/25
12/14 [========================>.....] - ETA: 10s - loss: 0.2092 - accuracy: 0.3945 - mse: 0.1044
```

Comment: Is your task multiclass or multilabel?

Comment: It is multiclass. I followed a tutorial on it, but used my own class names, data, pictures and csv file.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hraKTseOuJA&feature=youtu.be

The classes I had were "Normal cells, Ghost cells, Acanthocytes, parasites etc" 
There were over 1000 images of various weights, but I defined the weights above. 
Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some notes that might help:

- When using Batch Normalization, avoid too small batch sizes. For more details see the *Group Normalization* paper by Yuxin Wu and Kaiming He.
- It may worth looking at metrics like AUC, and F1 as well since you have an imbalanced multiclass case. You can add `tf.keras.metrics.AUC(curve='PR')` to your metrics list.
- The training loss seems to have stalled at the end of epoch 13. If the training loss does not decrease anymore, you may want to 1. use smaller learning rate, and/or 2. reduce your dropout parameters. Particularly, the relatively-large dropout right before your last layer seems suspicious to me. First, try to obtain a model that fits well your training dataset (with low to no dropout). That is an important step. If your model cannot fit well your training dataset without any regularization, it may need more trainable parameters. After achieving a minimum model that fits the training dataset, you can then add regularization mechanisms to mitigate the overfitting issue.
- Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise set `shuffle = True` (which is also the default setting) to shuffle the training data before each epoch.
- Although it is probably not the root cause of your problem, there is a debate on whether the normalization should come before the activation or after that. Some prefer to use it before the activation.
- The following was not clear to me:

> I then specify the sample weight which was calculated by taking the
> highest sampled number and divided the other numbers by that.

Your class weights may have already been calculated correctly. I'd like to emphasize though that an under-represented class should be assigned a larger weight. Refer to this [tutorial from TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data) as needed.

Comment: Hello. I have tried your suggestions above and will review my results. They worked. Thanks. 

__When using Batch Normalization, avoid too small batch sizes. For more details see the Group Normalization paper by Yuxin Wu and Kaiming He.__ 
I used larger batch sizes (nearly the size of the dataset) and it worked much better AND faster. 

__use `tf.keras.metrics.AUC(curve='PR')`__ 
I used this and it showed a higher auc than my accuracy. Very helpful. 

__1. use smaller learning rate, and/or 2. reduce your dropout parameters.__
Learning rate to 0.001 and Dropout to 0.1 only helped.

Comment: Regarding "it showed a higher auc than my accuracy", please note that they are two different metrics representing quite distinct concepts. Introducing different metrics does not change how good or bad you model really is. They just provide us with different information. Comparing those two metrics was not my point. My point was that the AUC-PR metric can be more **insightful** for classification on an imbalanced dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on that.
If I understand correctly, AUC being equal to 1 means the model is full and cannot improve accuracy much more? 
My accuracy is still only around 70%, however I found something else with my code. 
When I change the SIZE variable to a larger number it crashes the runtime (RAM). When I lower it, it fully runs. I also eliminated 2 classes that were vague.